# Colored image by Gabor Filters

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, grayscale, feature-extraction

I am using a Gabor Filter Code and Everything seems to run fine but I am having Problem with Output Image.
The Code I am using belongs from here : [Gabor Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003147/how-to-apply-gabor-wavelets-to-an-image)

I created `[4x8]` filters with 8 orientations each with varying wavelength.

[image: Gabor Filters]

Now I gave an image as input:

[image: Car]

So I got output as:

[image]

Am I not Supposed to get some image in Black and White.
I mean why is it colored.
When I check the dimension using `ndims(imgS)` It tell that image is 2-D.

For the sake of some clarity Here is the code where Image is convolved with above patches.:

```
function [img]=Convolve_Gabor(R,C,GW,img)
%if not grayscaled then grayscale it
if ndims(img)>2
    img=rgb2gray(img);
end

%Convert to Double so that its accepteble everywhere
img=im2double(img);

% Store the original size.
[m,n] = size(img);

%{
 The minimum amount of padding is just "one side" of the filter.
 We add 1 if the image size is odd.
 assuming the filter size is odd.
%}

pR = (R-1)/2; % make pR half of R
pC = (C-1)/2; % make pC half of C

if rem(m,2) ~= 0; pR = pR + 1; end; % if image height is odd make pR even
if rem(n,2) ~= 0; pC = pC + 1; end; % if image width is odd make pC even
img = padarray(img,[pR pC],'pre'); % Pad image to handle circular convolution.

% Pad all the filters to size of padded image.
% We made sure padsize will only be even, so we can divide by 2.
padsize = size(img) - [R C];
GW = cellfun( @(x) padarray(x,padsize/2),GW,'UniformOutput',false);

imgFFT = fft2(img); % Pre-calculate image FFT.
imgfilt={};
for i=1:length(GW)
    filter = fft2( ifftshift( GW{i} ) ); % See Numerical Recipes.
    imgfilt{i} = ifft2( imgFFT .* filter ); % Apply Convolution Theorem.
end

%# Sum the responses to each filter. Do it in the above loop to save some space.
imgS = zeros(m,n);

for i=1:length(imgfilt)
    imgS = imgS + imgfilt{i}(pR+1:end,pC+1:end); % Just use the valid part.
end
disp(ndims(imgS));
figure,imagesc(abs(imgS)),hold on;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because an image only has one channel, i.e., the data is a 2-D matrix, doesn't mean that it can't be transformed to three-dimensional RGB space. This technique is referred to as [indexed color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color) (as opposed to [truecolor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-color#True_color)). It looks like Matlab is using the default `jet` colormap to transform the data to color. If you want the image to display as grayscale, use the [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) function after plotting:

```
colormap(gray(256));
```

See [this blog post from The MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/how-matlab-represents-pixel-colors.html) for further details.

Comment: if u are a matlab user can u tell me how to use above obtained image as a feature vector to neaural network in matlab..
I am wondering what exactly should be taken as the features.
Individual responses or the whole image after convolution

Comment: @adil: I'm not really an image processing expert so I don't think I can help on that, and it's really a separate question from the one asked.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway...Yeah!!!that's a separate one it belongs to machine learning but I asked just in case :)