# How to apply gabor filter to images in opencv?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I've got some wavelets  with the gabor filter code, it's something like this..[image: wavelets]

but i don't know how to use it on my image? i know there are some ways with matlab,i.e [matlab way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003147/how-to-apply-gabor-wavelets-to-an-image?rq=1).  but I'm using `opencv`, and I'm very new to this field and `matlab`, I don't know how to write the opencv code from the matlab code, so , waht am I supposed to do this with `opencv`? thanks very much!

****Update****
I've tried @berak's way, and this is the original image [image]

and this is after I applied the filter [image] just all white and nothing left,below is my params,

```
int kernel_size = 31;
double sig = 1, th = 0, lm = 1.0, gm = 0.02, ps = 0;
cv::Mat kernel = cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size, kernel_size), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);
cv::filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);
```

is there anything wrong with my setting?

Comment: Just curious, what's in your original image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

basically, you convert your img to float,

then construct a kernel:

```
cv::Mat kernel = cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);
```

and apply it with filter2D:

```
cv::filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);
```

[edit]

** i'm not sure, but you'll probably need a 1channel image as input.

** imshow sees, your image is float, and just saturates anything beyond 1.0, so you get an all white image.

(this is just a visualization problem, needs a bit of conversion/scaling to cure it)

```
Mat in = imread("XfNal.jpg",0);          // load grayscale
Mat dest;
Mat src_f;
in.convertTo(src_f,CV_32F);

int kernel_size = 31;
double sig = 1, th = 0, lm = 1.0, gm = 0.02, ps = 0;
cv::Mat kernel = cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);
cv::filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);

cerr << dest(Rect(30,30,10,10)) << endl; // peek into the data

Mat viz;
dest.convertTo(viz,CV_8U,1.0/255.0);     // move to proper[0..255] range to show it
imshow("k",kernel);
imshow("d",viz);
waitKey();
```

[image: clip_gabor]

Comment: I don't get it, I use the code that I get from the web to generate the wavelets, and you mean I don't need it and just use these two lines and can apply gabor filter on my image? or can you please provide more details?

Comment: the 1st line constructs one wavelet, the 2nd applies it to the image. imho, that's all you ever need in opencv

Comment: I've tried but still don't get what I want. could you please see my update?

Comment: better now ? feel free to complain if not.

Comment: It works now, though the effect is not good enough,but it's another problem, maybe I should ask another question.

Comment: yes. good idea. then please refine, what 'good enough' would mean exactly. the current wavelet you're applying is just doing a vertical 1pixel blur, usually you got something more advanced there. try playng with the params, and applying several filter2d passes with different wavelets, aka a "filterbank"

Answer (score -6):

change sigma=3 lambda=36 theta=116 psi=274

Comment: Why? What's your rationale behind these parameters? How did you come up with these?

Comment: See the definition and especially psi. Imho your params incorrect. CV_EXPORTS_W Mat getGaborKernel( Size ksize, double sigma, double theta, double lambd,
                                 double gamma, double psi = CV_PI*0.5, int ktype = CV_64F );