# Reproduce MATLAB's imgaborfilt in Python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scikit-image, gabor-filter

I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of the following MATLAB code in Python:

```matlab
% Matlab code
wavelength = 10
orientation = 45
image = imread('filename.tif') % grayscale image
[mag,phase] = imgaborfilt(image, wavelength, orientation)
gabor_im = mag .* sin(phase)
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a license and cannot run the code. Also, the [official Matlab documentation of imgaborfilt](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html) does not specify precisely what the functions do.

For lack of an obvious alternative, I'm trying to use OpenCV in Python (open to other suggestions). I have no experience working with OpenCV. I'm trying to use `cv2.getGaborKernel` and `cv2.filter2D`. I could not find detailed documentation of the behaviour of these functions, either. Afaik there is no official documentation of the Python wrapper for OpenCV. The docstrings of the functions provide some information but it is incomplete and imprecise.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23077105/9988487), where OpenCV is used in C++ to solve the problem. I assume the functions work in a very similar way (also note the  [official C++ documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20filter2D(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType))). However, they have a number of additional parameters. **How can I find out what the matlab functions really do** to reproduce the behaviour?

```py
# python 3.6
import numpy as np
import cv2

wavelength = 10
orientation = 45
shape = (500, 400)  # arbitrary values to get running example code...
sigma = 100  # what to put for Matlab behaviour?
gamma = 1  # what to put for Matlab behaviour?
gabor_filter = cv2.getGaborKernel(shape, sigma, orientation, wavelength, gamma)
print(gabor_filter.shape)  # =(401, 501). Why flipped?

image = np.random.random(shape)  # create some random data.
out_buffer = np.zeros(shape)

destination_depth = -1  # like dtype for filter2D. Apparantly, -1="same as input".
thing = cv2.filter2D(image, destination_depth, gabor_filter, out_buffer)
print(out_buffer.shape, out_buffer.dtype, out_buffer.max())  # =(500, 400) float64 65.2..
print(thing.shape, thing.dtype, thing.max())  # =(500, 400) float64 65.2..
```

**EDIT:**

After receiving the great answer by Cris Luengo, I used it to make two functions, using OpenCV and scikit-image respectively, to (hopefully) reproduce MATLAB imgaborfit function behaviour. I include them here. Note that the scikit implementation is a lot slower than OpenCV.

I still have further questions about these functions:

- To what precision do
  the results of the OpenCV solution and the MATLAB solution agree?
- For people not wanting to use OpenCV, I also include a scikit-image solution
  here. I
  found parameters, such that the magnitudes are almost equal. However, it seems the phase of the scikit-image solution is different from the OpenCV solution. Why is this?

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2

def gaborfilt_OpenCV_likeMATLAB(image, wavelength, orientation, SpatialFrequencyBandwidth=1, SpatialAspectRatio=0.5):
    """Reproduces (to what accuracy in what MATLAB version??? todo TEST THIS!) the behaviour of MATLAB imgaborfilt function using OpenCV."""

    orientation = -orientation / 180 * math.pi # for OpenCV need radian, and runs in opposite direction
    sigma = 0.5 * wavelength * SpatialFrequencyBandwidth
    gamma = SpatialAspectRatio
    shape = 1 + 2 * math.ceil(4 * sigma)  # smaller cutoff is possible for speed
    shape = (shape, shape)
    gabor_filter_real = cv2.getGaborKernel(shape, sigma, orientation, wavelength, gamma, psi=0)
    gabor_filter_imag = cv2.getGaborKernel(shape, sigma, orientation, wavelength, gamma, psi=math.pi / 2)
    filtered_image = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, gabor_filter_real) + 1j * cv2.filter2D(image, -1, gabor_filter_imag)
    mag = np.abs(filtered_image)
    phase = np.angle(filtered_image)
    return mag, phase
```

```py
import numpy as np
import math
from skimage.filters import gabor

def gaborfilt_skimage_likeMATLAB(image, wavelength, orientation, SpatialFrequencyBandwidth=1, SpatialAspectRatio=0.5):
    """TODO (does not quite) reproduce the behaviour of MATLAB imgaborfilt function using skimage."""
    sigma = 0.5 * wavelength * SpatialFrequencyBandwidth
    filtered_image_re, filtered_image_im = gabor(
        image, frequency=1 / wavelength, theta=-orientation / 180 * math.pi,
        sigma_x=sigma, sigma_y=sigma/SpatialAspectRatio, n_stds=5,
    )
    full_image = filtered_image_re + 1j * filtered_image_im
    mag = np.abs(full_image)
    phase = np.angle(full_image)
    return mag, phase
```

Code to test above functions:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def show(im, title=""):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.title(f"{title}: dtype={im.dtype}, shape={im.shape},\n max={im.max():.3e}, min= {im.min():.3e}")
    plt.colorbar()

image = np.zeros((400, 400))
image[200, 200] = 1  # a delta impulse image to visualize the filtering kernel
wavelength = 10
orientation = 33  # in degrees (for MATLAB)

mag_cv, phase_cv = gaborfilt_OpenCV_likeMATLAB(image, wavelength, orientation)
show(mag_cv, "mag")  # normalized by maximum, non-zero noise even outside filter window region
show(phase_cv, "phase")  # all over the place

mag_sk, phase_sk = gaborfilt_skimage_likeMATLAB(image, wavelength, orientation)
show(mag_sk, "mag skimage")  # small values, zero outside filter region
show(phase_sk, "phase skimage")  # and hence non-zero only inside filter window region

show(mag_cv - mag_sk/mag_sk.max(), "cv - normalized(sk)")  # approximately zero-image.
show(phase_sk - phase_cv, "phase_sk - phase_cv") # phases do not agree at all! Not even in the window region!
plt.show()
```

Comment: The OpenCV documentation contains the documentation for the Python bindings too. I recommend that you look at the docs for newer versions of OpenCV. I don’t know which version you use, but docs typically improve over time. https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gae84c92d248183bd92fa713ce51cc3599 — All C++ parameters for this function are available from Python. This is the case for most functionality AFAIK.

Comment: The MATLAB docs you link for `imgaborfilt` are also pretty complete, not sure what other information you would be looking for? Do you know the basics of the Gabor filter?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I looked at the doc again and you're right. I was confused by the fact that Name-Value Pair Arguments are used, that are at the bottom of the page. Could you write an answer, including some example Python and MATLAB code, that both give the same result? I would do it myself but, as pointed out in the question, I can't test that the results match. Also perhaps it would make sense to include skimage.filter.gabor_filter as well, so this question at least has some use...

Comment: Actually, looking at the OpenCV Gabor kernels, it seems that they are real-valued. Whoever implemented Gabor filtering for OpenCV doesn't understand the Gabor filter. I will write an answer for you later, how to combine two same filters with different phase value to produce the correct complex-valued output. It's not difficult, but the library should do this for you. All OpenCV+Gabor tutorials I found in half a minute of Googling do it wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for both MATLAB's [`imgaborfilt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html) and OpenCV's [`getGaborKernel`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gae84c92d248183bd92fa713ce51cc3599) are almost complete enough to be able to do a 1:1 translation. Only a little bit of experimentation is needed to figure out how to translate MATLAB's "`SpatialFrequencyBandwidth`" to a sigma for the Gaussian envelope.

One thing that I've noticed here is that OpenCV's implementation of Gabor filtering seems to indicate that Gabor filters are not well understood. A quick Google exercise demonstrates that the most popular tutorials for Gabor filtering in OpenCV do not properly understand Gabor filters.

The Gabor filter, as can be learned for example from the same [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter) that OpenCV's documentation links to, is a complex-valued filter. The result of applying it to an image is therefore also complex-valued. MATLAB correctly returns the magnitude and phase of the complex result, rather than the complex-valued image itself, since it is mostly the magnitude that is of interest. The magnitude of the Gabor filter indicates which parts of an image have frequencies of the given wavelength and orientation.

For example, one can apply a Gabor filter to this image (left) to yield this result (right) (this is the magnitude of the complex-valued output):

[image: image and result of a Gabor filter]

However, OpenCV's filtering seems to be strictly real-valued. It is possible to build a real-valued component of the Gabor filter kernel with an arbitrary phase. Gabor's filter has a real component with 0 phase and an imaginary component with π/2 phase (that is, the real component is even and the imaginary component is odd). Combining the even and the odd filters allows one to analyze a signal with arbitrary phase, creating filters with other phases is unnecessary.

---

To replicate the following MATLAB code:

```matlab
image = zeros(64,64); 
image(33,33) = 1;     % a delta impulse image to visualize the filtering kernel

wavelength = 10;
orientation = 30; # in degrees
[mag,phase] = imgaborfilt(image, wavelength, orientation);
% defaults: 'SpatialFrequencyBandwidth'=1; 'SpatialAspectRatio'=0.5
```

in Python with OpenCV one would need to do:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

image = np.zeros((64, 64))
image[32, 32] = 1          # a delta impulse image to visualize the filtering kernel

wavelength = 10
orientation = -30 / 180 * math.pi    # in radian, and seems to run in opposite direction
sigma = 0.5 * wavelength * 1         # 1 == SpatialFrequencyBandwidth
gamma = 0.5                          # SpatialAspectRatio
shape = 1 + 2 * math.ceil(4 * sigma) # smaller cutoff is possible for speed
shape = (shape, shape)
gabor_filter_real = cv2.getGaborKernel(shape, sigma, orientation, wavelength, gamma, psi=0)
gabor_filter_imag = cv2.getGaborKernel(shape, sigma, orientation, wavelength, gamma, psi=math.pi/2)

gabor = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, gabor_filter_real) + 1j * cv2.filter2D(image, -1, gabor_filter_imag)
mag = np.abs(gabor)
phase = np.angle(gabor)
```

Do note that it is important for the input image to be of a floating-point type, otherwise the computation result will be cast to a type that cannot represent all the values needed to represent the result of the Gabor filter.

---

The last line of the code in the OP is

```matlab
gabor_im = mag .* sin(phase)
```

This is, to me, very strange and I wonder what this code was used for. What it accomplishes is obtaining the result of the imaginary component of the Gabor filter:

```py
gabor_im = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, gabor_filter_imag)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I think your last statement concerning `gabor_im` is incorrect. Surely it is the imaginary part of the filtered image, not of  the filter kernel itself (This Im(gabor_filt(image)) really is what I need, by the way. The imaginary part is used for hashing, "since" it is indifferent to DC components).

Comment: I updated my question with an attempt to make functions that reproduce the MATLAB behaviour using OpenCV and scikit-image. However, I still have some questions about them (the two solutions currently do not agree). Could you comment on this?

Comment: @Adomas: Indeed, I copy-pasted the wrong statement, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Adomas: I can look at your skimage solution later. But you should really not be using floating-point computations for hashes. You will likely not get the same exact result in two different computers, let alone with two different implementations of the concept. There are many, many things that could be different, including boundary extension (padding), order of operations, internal precision of operations, truncation of the Gaussian envelope, etc. these are things we don’t control and also have no insight into in case of MATLAB.

Comment: @Chris Luengo This is only part of the computation of the hash. If you're interested in the details, check out e.g. this paper: 
Pappu, R. Physical One-Way Functions. Science 297, 2026–2030 (2002).

Comment: @Adomas: Hashing should see the data as a series of bytes, and only apply integer arithmetic. Floating-point arithmetic is simply not suitable for hashing because it is not exactly reproducible. Even rounding to a certain number of digits does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Chirs perhaps "Hashing" is not the most appropriate word, although its use seems standard in the field (dealing with PUFs, Physical Unclonable Functions), as is this way of computing it. The idea of the method is to take a a high-resolution chaotic 2D image and use it to calculate a bistring, which mustn't be too sensitive to noise among other requirements. Certainly the precise implementation of the calculation matters a lot for this, which is why it's important to compare them in detail. However, there shouldn't be a way to avoid flops to achieve this task. Thanks for your concern, though!